# jquery array json push multidimensional

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I need to create json to jquery on the fly.
Entering page content balances the database.
The tag automatically generates an insertion in several databases ...
I'm stuck on the generation of the multidimensional array

```
expected result : {"rh" : [{"name":"me"}, {"surname":"doe"}]}

input db = rh
input name => name and surname
input val => me and doe
```

html :

```
<div class="form-group row mb-4">
    <label for="rh_prenom_label" class="col-form-label col-lg-2">Prénom</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input id="rh_prenom" name="rh_pid" what="prenom" db="rh" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Prénom de la ressource..." />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row mb-4">
    <label for="rh_prenom_label" class="col-form-label col-lg-2">Date de naissance</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input id="rh_prenom" name="rh_pid" what="date_naissance" db="rh" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-autoclose="true" />
    </div>
</div>
```

js :

```
$("[name='" + who + "']").each(function (index) {
    console.info(index + ": " + $(this).attr("what") + " :: " + $(this).val() + " | " + $(this).attr("db"));

    var what = $(this).attr("what");
    var db = $(this).attr("db");
    var item = {};

    item[what] = $(this).val();
    jsonObj.push(item);
});
```

Comment: Hi what is `who` in your jquery code ?